# ¿Cómo evitar que los datos se repitan en una consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una consulta en mysql, pero cuando me muestra la consulta, los datos se repiten muchas veces, esta es la consulta y las tablas:

```
SELECT Boleta.NroBoleta,FechaAlquiler,idPelicula,PrecioAlquilado FROM Boleta,detalleBoleta

CREATE TABLE Pelicula(
idPelicula varchar(5) not null,
titulo varchar(80) not null,
tipo enum('Comedia', 'Accion', 'Terror', 'Drama') default "Comedia" not null,
categoria enum ('Estreno', 'Normal', 'Clasico') default "Estreno" not null,
actorPrincipal varchar(50) not null,
precioActual int(11) not null,
stock int(11) not null,
saldo int(11) not null,
constraint pk_pelicula primary key (idPelicula)
);

CREATE TABLE Cliente(
idCliente varchar(12) not null,
nombre varchar(50) not null,
apellido1 varchar(50) not null,
apellido2 varchar(50) not null,
documento int(11) not null,
direccion varchar(80) not null,
telefono varchar(10) not null,
celular varchar(10) not null,
constraint pk_cliente primary key (idCliente)
);

CREATE TABLE Boleta(
NroBoleta varchar(5) not null,
FechaAlquiler datetime not null,
idCliente varchar(12) not null,
constraint pk_boleta primary key (NroBoleta),
constraint fk_idCliente foreign key (idCliente) references Cliente (idCliente)
);

CREATE TABLE detalleBoleta(
NroBoleta varchar(5) not null,
idPelicula varchar(5) not null,
precioAlquilado int(11) not null,
devuelto enum('SI', 'NO') not null,
fechaDevolucion datetime not null,
diasMora int(11) not null,
constraint fk_NroBoleta foreign key (NroBoleta) references Boleta (NroBoleta),
constraint fk_idPelicula foreign key (idPelicula) references Pelicula
(idPelicula)
);
```

Esta es la consulta que me mandaron a hacer:

> 5. Mostrar las boletas emitidas la primera semana del mes en curso. El resultado debe incluir: No. Boleta y fecha de alquiler de la tabla `boleta`, id película y precio alquilado de la tabla `detalle boleta`.

No sé cómo hacer que no se repitan, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa los datos, puede que estén duplicados en las tablas o puede que las relaciones entre las tablas no estén bien. Para depurar haz primero una consulta con la 1ª tabla y revisa si no se repiten, si es así agrega la(s) siguiente(s) tabla(s) y cuando empiecen a repetirse sabrás dónde está el problema. En tu consulta tampoco se ve el ' WHERE` por el que se va a filtrar.

Comment: Podrias probar cambiar en vez de traer el NroBoleta de la tabla Boleta de  detalleBoleta, en caso que siga duplicando agrega la cláusula Distinct

Comment: @MaximilianoFlores Como así amigo?

Comment: 1- proba Select detalleBoleta.NroBoleta .... 2- en caso que continúe duplicando Select distinct nroBoleta ....

Comment: Sugiero que publiques como parte de tu pregunta la consulta que actualmente estás realizando y donde se te duplican los datos, para partir de allí. De otra manera, esta más bien parece una solicitud para que alguien haga tu tarea/trabajo. Un saludo.

Comment: Tus datos se van a repetir porque estas haciendo FROM Boleta,detalleBoleta lo que genera un producto cartesiano entre esas dos tablas. Las relaciones que hayas creado a la hora de crear las tablas no se replican automaticamente en las consultas. Revisa como usar clausulas JOIN en el from

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar varias tablas en una consulta requiere unirlas de acuerdo a alguna clave común entre ambas tablas (primaria/foranea/etc), esta union/correlacion no es automatica.

En este caso pareciera que `NroBoleta` es el campo que las relaciona, por lo que agregando la condicion `Boleta.NroBOleta=detalleBoleta.NroBoleta` deberia entregar los registros especificos:

```
SELECT Boleta.NroBoleta,FechaAlquiler,idPelicula,PrecioAlquilado
FROM Boleta,detalleBoleta
WHERE Boleta.NroBOleta=detalleBoleta.NroBoleta
```

De igual manera cuando hayan varias tablas, todas ellas deben unirse por los campos en comun que posean, segun las relaciones establecidas entre las tablas.

Answer (score 1):

como han indicado en otros comentarios has de cruzar las tablas ya que de lo contrario estarías creando un producto cartesiano. Si después de cruzar las tablas aun así hay duplicados por como es la consulta puedes utilizar "DISTINCT" para eliminar los duplicados.

ejemplo de uso de distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NOMBRE FROM TABLA_EJEMPLO
```